# Check if list is sorted in python

Tags: python

Write the in_order() function, which has a list of integers as a parameter, and returns True if the integers are sorted (in order from low to high) or False otherwise. The program outputs "In order" if the list is sorted, or "Not in order" if the list is not sorted.

Ex: If the list passed to the in_order() function is [5, 6, 7, 8, 3], then the function returns False and the program outputs:

Not in order
Ex: If the list passed to the in_order() function is [5, 6, 7, 8, 10], then the function returns True and the program outputs:

In order
Note: DO NOT use sorted() or sort().

My code works but for all except this one:

Test in_order(nums) returns True, where nums is [5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10]

```
def in_order(nums):
    return all(nums[i-1] < nums[i] for i in range(1, len(nums)))
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Test out-of-order example
    nums1 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 3]
    if in_order(nums1):
        print('In order')
    else:
        print('Not in order')
        
    # Test in-order example
    nums2 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 10]
    if in_order(nums2):
        print('In order')
    else:
        print('Not in order')
```

Comment: why is the last one not sorted? it seems like so to me

Comment: wild guess: `nums[i-1] < nums[i]` => `nums[i-1] <= nums[i]`

Comment: Your function doesn't allow for duplicate values in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the function need to be two lines of code with `<=` operators, to detect `low to high` and `high to low` list and equal sequences.

```
def in_order(nums):
    a = [nums[i-1] <= nums[i] for i in range(1, len(nums))]
    return all(x == a[0] for x in a)
```

```
[8, 6, 5, 4]
In order
[5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10]
In order
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use zip() to compare each element with its successor and the all() function to check if all of these comparions return True:

```
def in_order(nums): 
    return all(a<=b for a,b in zip(nums,nums[1:]))
```